# How to add author template in existing files on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to add this

```
/**
 * Created by cyborn on 1/10/15.
 */
```

template to my existing Java files in Android Studio.

Comment: Do you have a question, or did you just want us to know?

Comment: yes , ihave a question and i couldn't find the exact answer (maybe i didn't understand them properly) on google , so i post it here. Thanks for asking

Answer (score -2, accepted):

From File > Settings, open "Editor" tab. Select "File and Code Templates". Click on "Includes" tab. You can define your own template and define your variables.

```
#set ($USER = "Basim")
/**
 * Created by ${USER} on ${DATE}.
 */
```

Comment: this actually does not quite answer the question. It won't add the comment to "existing" files.

Comment: Not specific answer to question

Comment: Down voting as this doesn't solve the problem of adding it to the existing files

Comment: this doesn't add the template to the existing files